# Google apis return null even though it worked fine in US. I am developing the same app from India

Tags: android, google-maps

This is the URL I am using:

> "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&rankby=distance&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=MyKey"

I tried using both browser and android keys but it did not work.

I also tried using POST method along with GET but both of them failed. I keep getting null.

I was developing on the same app in US and it worked fine. Does anyone has any ideas?

Just to confirm I have switched to the default using GET method with browser key but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that the lat, long you are supplying for the maps is pointed at some location which may not be mapped. It may be something located near an open field, or a something of that sort. Did you try adding the lat, long of a major city in India to check if it still returns null?

Comment: The lat long locations are located in the heart of mumbai city. Also I tried some hardcoded lat long values like New York city but even that did not work. Not sure why

Comment: I am using a different phone though for running and debugging my app..Previously I used Sony Xperia now I am using Samsung Galaxy core

Comment: Do you mean to say it doesnt work on some phones and works for others?